# When the indexer runs in Production mode?

Tags: magento2, cron, reindexing

When a **Magento2** instance is in **Production Mode**, **When the re-indexing takes place automatically** or Do we have to **create cron for re-indexing**.
Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup crons (manually or by using magento cron:install), after that it is taken care of. It also depends on how the indexers are configured (on save or schedule).
For more information on both topics

- [Magento DevDocs - Configure and run cron](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)
- [Magento DevDocs - Manage the indexers](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html)